# How can I make formula to calculate the number in the new string with the condition

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

Heres is my input
[image]

I expect to have new string `3-3-2-10-3-2` corresponding to the `LO-JOB-SD-MDD-JOB-SD`
I explained it in this below picture
[image]
Please help. Thank you!

Comment: With Excel-2010 I'd say it's best to do that with an UDF unless you want to use some helper cells etc.

Comment: Wouldn't the output have to be 3-3-4-5-3-4 following the logic mentioned?

Comment: @P.b the output in the question is correct 3*1 - 6*0.5 - 4*1 - 10*1 - 6*0.5 - 4*0.5

Answer (score 1):

Edit :

1] Try this formula solution, work with your Excel 2010 and up

2] Number of the element in Step and Weight >> 2 to 7 elements (Max.7)

3] In `G2`, array formula copied down (confirm entered with "Ctrl"+"Shift"+"Enter") :

```
=LEFT(TEXT(SUM(IFERROR(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE("-"&B2,"-",REPT(" ",99)),ROW($1:$8)*99,99))*INDEX(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE("-"&E$2,"-",REPT(" ",99)),ROW($1:$8)*99,99)),N(IF(1,MATCH(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE("-"&A2,"-",REPT(" ",99)),ROW($1:$8)*99,99)),TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE("-"&D$2,"-",REPT(" ",99)),ROW($1:$8)*99,99)),0)))),0)*10^{14;12;10;8;6;4;2;0}),"00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00"),(LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"-",""))+1)*3-1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help. However when I reduce some element in Step and Weight. Your formula didn't work for me. Example I Input  LO-JOB-SD-MDD  in Step and 1-0.5-1-1 in Weight . That formula returned #VALUE!

Comment: What is the maximum number of the element in Step and Weight ? Excel 2010 can use max. 8 elements, otherwise change to use Excel 2019.

Comment: Yes In this my case I use any elements that is < =8 elements. The problem here is your formula did not work when I change elements number in Step and Weight That I mentioned above

Comment: Assuming Step: LO-JOB ,Weight: 1-0.5. Output return #VALUE!

Comment: After the further checking of my modified formula, I found that the max. no of elements is 7 not 8, so if you accept of this >> range from 2 to7 elements, I shall post out this modified formula.

Comment: Sure,  I really expect it

Comment: Is that a way to get accuracy decimal element value in OUTPUT like  : 12.5-2.5-0.3.-0.05

Comment: No, the formula designed for 2 digits per each element only, unless you have Excel 2019 or Office 365 Textjoin function.

Comment: Sure I'm using Excel 2019. That exist textjoin formula